# Curl Post or Node/Express server converting double quotes to single quotes

Tags: json, node.js, express, curl

I am sending a POST request from curl like this:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type:application/json" -X POST -d '{"key":"value"}' http://localhost:3000/parsejson
```

However, I am getting on my Node/Express server:

```
{'key':'value'} // req.body
```

So it is unclear to me if it is the curl request or the configuration of my node server. On my node server, I'm using: bodyParser.json() and bodyParser.urlencoded()

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all this line is incorrect and you cannot run curl with that:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type:application/json" -X POST -d '{"key":"value"}' http://localhost:3000/parsejson
```

I'm mentioning it because this is a question about single and double quotes and you have single and double quotes messed up in your example of how you make a request, resulting in a code that cannot possibly be executed. Since this is obviously not how you really make the request, it is not clear how you do.

Now, if you want to see what you really get in the request, then **don't** use a body parser (temporarily switch it off, remove or comment it out) and run `req.pipe(process.stdout)` to display the request body on the server. Then you will know what you are getting from the client.

Also run curl with the `-v` option to see what it is actually sending.

If it turns out that curl is sending a correct JSON and your server gets a correct JSON in the request body then your problem must be somewhere else than in topics that you are asking about in this question.

Of course it's impossible to tell you what is the problem in that case because you didn't include even a single line of code in your question.